# NEAT C++ Compiler errors Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, neat

I would like to run the following C++ library (from 2010) under Microsoft Visual Studio 2012:

http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/?neat-c

I already fixed a lot of compiler errors, but for some issues I find no solution.
The compiler errors are:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: My_Neuronal_Network, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  species.cpp
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\species.cpp(454): warning C4101: 'spin' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\species.cpp(433): warning C4101: 'pause' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\species.cpp(453): warning C4101: 'marble' : unreferenced local variable
1>  population.cpp
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\population.cpp(71): warning C4101: 'count' : unreferenced local variable
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\population.cpp(432): warning C4101: 'pause' : unreferenced local variable
1>  genome.cpp
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1777): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1790): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1795): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1845): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1862): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1884): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1888): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1961): warning C4101: 'p1innov' : unreferenced local variable
1>  experiments.cpp
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(52): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(52): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(52): error C2133: 'evals' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(53): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(53): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(53): error C2133: 'genes' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(54): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(54): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(54): error C2133: 'nodes' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(316): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(316): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(316): error C2133: 'runs' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(512): error C3861: 'lrand48': identifier not found
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(513): error C3861: 'lrand48': identifier not found
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(514): error C3861: 'lrand48': identifier not found
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(515): error C3861: 'lrand48': identifier not found
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(573): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(575): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(580): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(581): warning C4305: 'initializing' : truncation from 'double' to 'const float'
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(623): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(623): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(623): error C2133: 'record' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(625): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(625): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(625): error C2133: 'genesrec' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(627): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(627): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(627): error C2133: 'nodesrec' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(629): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(629): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(629): error C2133: 'winnergens' : unknown size
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(692): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\experiments.cpp(706): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>  Generating Code...
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(543): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'bias' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1948): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'newgene' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1533): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'newnode' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1777): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'nodep1' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1777): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'nodep2' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1808): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'newgene' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1531): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'newgene1' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(1532): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'newgene2' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(2500): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'chosengene' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(2151): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'chosengene' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\genome.cpp(2794): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'chosengene' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\population.cpp(90): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'new_genome' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\population.cpp(289): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'new_genome' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\population.cpp(546): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'best_species' used
1>c:\users\sebi\desktop\neuroevolution\neat.1.2.1\neat.1.2.1\species.cpp(89): error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'thechamp' used
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In neat.cpp there is the following defined:

```
%neat.cpp
...
int NEAT::num_runs = 1;
...
```

The first error occurs then at:

```
%experiments.cpp
 int evals[NEAT::num_runs];  //Hold records for each run
```

So somehow this value is not constant. I changes nothing at all if I use const int NEAT::num_runs=1;

Has Someone already used this library and was able to run this under visual studio?

Best Regards 
Sebi

Comment: The code depends on a non-standard GCC extension, VLAs are not legal in standard C++.  Rewriting it is not practical, you must use GCC.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I use now codeblocks with the gcc compiler. There are some POSIX functions in there, that are not available under Windows. What alternatives to strdup() I have on Windows?

Comment: On Windows it looks like the function is called _strdup(), but the compiler still says: "_strdup(..) was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 1):

**Essential errors**

```
error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable
```

this error solved just by initialing variable with *NULL*. But actually it is not an error, it is warning and it might be turned off in project settings.

Error occurs in `genome.cpp, population.cpp, species.cpp`

So C4703 is only error in 
essential part of NEAT implementation, which means it might be easily compiled with Visual C++.

Other errors occurs in usage of NEAT for solving pole-balancing tasks. They might be treated just as examples of usage NEAT.

> Has Someone already used this library and was able to run this under visual studio?

I have extracted NEAT to static link library which can be used in other Visual Studio projects. And there is second project in solution as example of usage NEAT.lib

[You can check my solution here](https://github.com/magzhan-abdibay/NEAT)

**Not essential errors**

```
error C3861: 'lrand48': identifier not found
```

Just use rand() in VisualC++.

```
error C2133: 'evals' : unknown size
```

`int evals[NEAT::num_runs];` - you can use this in Visual C++ only if  `NEAT::num_runs` is `const`. Value of `num_runs` must be known for compiler.

`int *evalsPtr = new int[NEAT::num_runs];` - in other case use this

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is fairly small for VC, so using `rand()` instead of `lrand48` may not suffice.

Comment: @Joey I agree with you. But in scope of this project `rand() ` is pretty enough. Is there any better alternatives of `lrand48 ` on Windows,Visual C++ ?

Comment: Well, if the lower `RAND_MAX` is not a problem then it should be okay, but as soon as you need a number larger than 32767 it would be, so I wasn't comfortable simply recommending `rand()` as a replacement.